# C# Return Results of Dictionary Lookup or if NULL return something else

Tags: c#

Here is my current function (it works but wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it).

```
public static Dictionary<int, double> profileNetworkLowCostPriorityList;

public static double DetermineNetworkSortOrderValue(int network, double fee)
{
    if (profileNetworkLowCostPriorityList == null) return fee;
    if (profileNetworkLowCostPriorityList[network] != null) return profileNetworkLowCostPriorityList[network];
    return fee;
}
```

Basically, if the `Dictonary` object is not null and there was something found in the dictonary, return that something. If not, return something else. My concern is in referencing a null dictionary object and that throwing an error. I can of course catch the error and return something but not sure if that is the best approach.

This code will run up to hundreds of millions of times for each "widget" we process so looking for an "efficient way" to do this.

Comment: return profileNetworkLowCostPriorityList != null ? (profileNetworkLowCostPriorityList[network] ?? fee) : fee;

Comment: "Note: the `Dictionary<int, double>` doesn't want to work in pre tags" - please read the formatting tips for how to format code. Just indent the whole block four spaces instead of using `<pre>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want `TryGetValue`, basically:

```
public static double DetermineNetworkSortOrderValue(int network, double fee)
{
    double dictionaryFee;
    return profileNetworkLowCostPriorityList == null ||
        !profileNetworkLowCostPriorityList.TryGetValue(network, out dictionaryFee)
        ? fee : dictionaryFee;
}
```

Also note that your current code *doesn't* work at the moment - if there's no dictionary entry for the network, an exception will be thrown. You should also be seeing a compile-time warning like this:

> The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'double' is never equal to 'null' of type 'double?'

Don't ignore warnings like that. I'd also *strongly* advise you not to expose public fields...

Comment: Thanks for your help. TryGetValue is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know about it. In exposing public fields, do you mean to make `profileNetworkLowCostPriorityList ` private and write getter and setter methods on it?

Comment: @thomas: Well, you *could* expose a property - but I suspect you'd be better off thinking carefully about *exactly* what operations you actually need to expose on it. Where does the data come from? Could you load it separately, and then effectively use it as a read-only data source? We don't have the context to tell you how to fix it, but public fields are almost always a bad idea - and public *static* fields even more so. ("Here's some global state - do what you like with it, whenever you like!")